# Failed to grant permission in JUnit (espresso) recorded test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, android-espresso

When I record an espresso test and replay it, I receive this error, how can I solve it? :

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see
>   logcat for details at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50) at
>   android.support.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:110)
>   at
>   android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:128)
>   at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2108)

Comment: Which permission? `PermissionRequester` can't grant privilege and not declared at manifest permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It solved by adding all permission which I added in unit test to Manifest.